# Converting $ajax to fetch() for PUT request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, fetch-api

I have tried to translate the following jquery code to use the fetch API instead. It makes a `PUT` request:

```
function save () {
  $.ajax('/{{user.username}}', {
    method: 'PUT',
    data: {
      street: $('#street').val(),
      city: $('#city').val(),
      state: $('#state').val(),
      zip: $('#zip').val()
    },
    complete: function () {
      cancel()
      location.reload()
    }
  })
}
```

This is the fetch API request:

```
fetch('/{{user.username}}', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application.json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
     street: document.getElementById("street").value,
     city: document.getElementById("city").value,
     state: document.getElementById("state").value,
     zip: document.getElementById("zip").value
  })
}).then(() => {
  cancel()
  location.reload()
})
}
```

When I `console.log` it to the terminal with Node I get an empty array.

I am trying to process it in Express with the following:

```
app.put('/:username', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log("hello")
  var username = req.params.username
  var user = getUser(username)
  user.location = req.body
  saveUser(username, user)
  res.end()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using bodyParser in Express because otherwise the jQuery version would not work.

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application.json'
},
```

should be

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
```